# ErrorException file_get_contents(C:\wamp64\www\casting\.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel-8, .env

I'm trying to run a laravel project on wampserver.

I have the following structure:

[image]

I executed the following commands :

```
composer update
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

And when I run this Cmd: `php artisan key:generate`, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException

  file_get_contents(C:\wamp64\www\casting\.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at C:\wamp64\www\casting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
```

I don't know what I should do.

Comment: That image is just awful to look at. Please never take pictures of the screen with a camera

Comment: From the scree shot, the file name is `.env.env` while you're trying to open `.env` file with file_get_contents. Try and rename your file from .env.env to .env

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file .env.env to .env only